# Assembly MASM Event Driven just like JAVA

Tags: java, events, assembly

Is it possible to have event driven programming moving objects or characters in a cmd screen. And how?

For example a chess board when you do a move then we have to print for each move. We want to play it only one chess board.

Thanks..:)

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: We stopped writing chess programs in assembly in the 1980's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to make out what you're asking, but I think I hear two different questions:

1. > Is it possible to do event-driven programming in assembly language?

   Yes, it is. In fact, quite a lot of assembly-language programming is event-driven (handling interrupts and such).
2. > Is it possible to write to specific parts of the console display rather than just outputting a stream of characters that scrolls?

   Yes, on nearly all consoles. *How* you do so varies a bit by console. You could look into [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) or similar, which work on a wide variety of console displays.

Comment: for example, we want to play a game on the black screen with only one board.we dont want it to be printed every time we play a move.we want to make it just a regular event handling operation.for example if we pressed space character, the next move will be appeared on the same board.

Comment: @chara: I understand. Yes, it *can* be done. I wouldn't choose those tools (MASM and console output) to do it, though. Choose the right tools for the job. In this case, just about any GUI toolkit and high-level language would be better choices.

Comment: ok thanks a lot.it is mandatory for our project.it is stupid,but mandatory.

Comment: @chara: Good luck with it. Definitely look into ANSI escape codes (link above).